# how to use php sessions and svelte together

Tags: php, svelte

I'm using php for my application backend. I created a authentication system with two loginUser.php and loginCheck.php

In loginUser.php when username and password is correct:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['bookstore_username'] = $_POST['username'];
session_write_close();

$response = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'user successfully authorized.', 'data' => $row);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Then in loginCheck.php

```
session_start();

 
if (isset($_SESSION["bookstore_username"]) && $_SESSION["bookstore_username"] == $_POST['username']) {
       $response = array('status' => true, 'message' => "user is logged in.");
       echo json_encode($response);
   } else {
       $response = array('status' => false, 'message' => "user is not logged in.");
       echo json_encode($response);
   }
```

When i testing it in Postman Application everything is fine and response showed me user logged in but in svelte app after doing a user login when i check login stat response is always false and session is null.

```
const checkUserIsLoggedIn = async (): Promise<void> => {
        const url = ORIGIN + "Backend/api/user/loginCheck.php";

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append("username", userInformationStore?.get().username);

        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
        });

        let response = await res.json();

        console.log(response);
    };
```

Comment: There is some scary confusing stuff in there.  Very naive to take user input from the $_POST and set your session variables based on that.   The things you use in session to detect the user and login state should not be directly set from the data posted by the user.  At any rate, one thing I notice immediately is that you don't set `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` for your scripts that return json using echo.

Comment: @gview I shared a part of my code only. I have observed this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the session relies on a cookie, the only explanation I see for the Session being null is that the session cookie is not being passed back to your back-end. By default, `fetch` only allows same-origin cookies. Try adding the following option to your `fetch` operation to allow cookies to be passed in cross-origin requests:

```js
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
            credentials: "include",
        });
```

See [this paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#differences_from_jquery) in the Fetch API documentation for details.